# Network status retry callback

Tags: android, kotlin, callback, call, kotlin-coroutines

I have an API that returns the network status and I want to add retry and cancel function for the API call

```
@GET("{path1}/{path2}")
suspend fun status(
    @HeaderMap headers: Map<String, String>
): Status?
```

This is the service class from where the API is called

```
override suspend fun status(): Status? =
    service.status(
        path1 = PATH_ONE,
        path2 = PATH_TWO,
        headers = mapOf(
            USER_AGENT to userAgent,
            ACCEPT to accept,
            ACCEPT_LANGUAGE to locale,
            X_APP_GUID to xAppGuid
        )
    )
```

The issue that I am facing is that to use the retrofit2.enqueue() and retrofit2.cancel() functions I need to change the return type of the status() function to Call, but then I face the issue that I cannot return that to the user, because Call() is an interface and cannot instantiated, and I need to return the actual status.

Does anyone have any clue how to do it?

Comment: Suspend functions in Retrofit are cancellable by cancelling whatever coroutine has called them. You can cancel a coroutine by hanging onto the Job reference returned by `launch` in a property and calling cancel on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Retrofit with Coroutines you do NOT need to use `Call`.

`suspend` functions (returned by Retrofit) are cancellable and will try to cancel the call when canceled. That means that:

```
myScope.launch { status(...) }
```

will be canceled whenever `myScope` is canceled. You can alternately keep a reference to the returned `Job` and cancel that yourself.

For retrying you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46890009/1011435)

```
retryIO(times = 3) { status(...) }
```