Spring @Retryable is not working on Kotlin suspend fun
I'm trying to add retry logic on my @Service method and it's not working if the method is suspend. (It's Kotlin/Gradle/Spring project).
Below is the working  method (just for test):
@Retryable(maxAttempts = 3, backoff =  Backoff(delay = 1000) )
fun getPerson(): Person {
    val random = (1..2).random()
    return runBlocking {

        println("random=$random,  ${if (random == 1) "exception" else "success"} ")

        if (random == 1) throw IllegalStateException("Exception occurred")

        Person("Name")
    }
}

And the method with suspend is not working:
@Retryable(maxAttempts = 3,backoff =  Backoff(delay = 1000))
suspend fun getPersonSuspend(): Person {
    val random = (1..2).random()
    println("random=$random,  ${if (random == 1) "exception" else "success"} ")
    if (random == 1) throw IllegalStateException("Exception occurred")

    return Person("Name")

}

Is that a normal behavior or do i miss something? The whole example is here.

When you say "it's not working", do you mean that Spring doesn't retry, but instead immediately returns a 500 error?

yes, it makes just  one attempt

It might be related to this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/issues/303 - it's still an open issue and no-one seems to be actively working on it.

but there is no async call  in my example

That's why I didn't say it's the same issue, but that it might be related. It may be worth adding a note to that issue to say that it appears to not work even without an async call, despite the original poster saying it does work.

Well, that's correct. There is no any async retry support in Spring Retry. Whether that is suspend, Mono or just Future. It is very complex task to achieve, especially when we would like to have back off as async as well. More info this PR: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/pull/176

This SO thread might give some ideas how to implement retry for your suspend function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46872242/how-to-exponential-backoff-retry-on-kotlin-coroutines. But as you see it does not use Spring Retry. However instead of repeat() and delay() you definitely can use RetryTemplate. The only the problem that declarative @Retryable does not work with those async methods. We will look into that next year.
